# Django form fields not in crispy form helper are not showing up

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have this form of a credit card gateway:

```
class CreditCardForm(forms.Form):
    SessionId = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    CardHolderName = forms.CharField(label=ugettext('Cardholder Name'), max_length=64, required=True)
    CardNumber = forms.CharField(label=ugettext("Card Number"), min_length=12, max_length=20, required=True)
    ExpiryMonth = forms.CharField(label="", min_length=2, max_length=2, required=True)
    ExpiryYear = forms.CharField(label="", min_length=2, max_length=2, required=True)
    Cvc2 = forms.CharField(label=ugettext("CVC"), min_length=3, max_length=4, required=True)
    UserTxnData1 = forms.CharField(label=ugettext("Card Alias"), max_length=64, required=False)
    helper = Helper()
```

And this Helper that I would like to reuse for different credit card gateways:

```
class Helper(FormHelper):
    layout = Layout(Fieldset('Card Details',
          RowFluid(Column(Field('CardHolderName',css_class="large-8 small-12")),
          RowFluid(Column(Field('CardNumber',css_class="large-8 small-12")),
          RowFluid(Column(Field('ExpiryMonth',css_class="large-8 small-12")),
          RowFluid(Column(Field('ExpiryYear',css_class="large-8 small-12")),
          RowFluid(Column(Field('Cvc2',css_class="large-8 small-12")),
          RowFluid(Column(Field('UserTxnData1',css_class="large-8 small-12")),
     ))
```

The problem is, `SessionId` is specific to this gateway form and it's not defined in the helper and it's not showing up in the rendered form.

Answer (score 0):

I think crispy forms only shows things you define in the layout helper if you use one. To make that field hidden try adding it as a field and adding something like this to your form:

```
class Meta:
    model = YourModel
    fields = (
        'session_id',
        ..., # all the fields you want to include
    )
    widgets = {
        'session_id': forms.HiddenInput(),
    }
```